# es6 classes and adding an explicit prototype to share across class instances

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

So, I have a class:

```
class XYZ {
    constructor(name) {
        if (!new.target) new XYZ(name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    run() {

    }

    walk() {

    }

   addShoe() {
       // I want to add a shoe here IF it hasn't already been 
       // added, by    any other instance
   }
}
```

Now, I need all of my instances to share a variable, ie: SHOES.

The only way I am figuring to do this, well two ways is either add a variable outside the class ( top of module ) OR put it on the prototype.
ie

I've tried adding static variables, not working. Of course I could just use a set/get, but again - that is a method that would still have to "access/update" the "shared variable resource"..

```
let SHOES = new Set();
//or
XYZ.prototype.SHOES =  new Set();
class XYZ {
    constructor(name) {
        if (!new.target) new XYZ(name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    run() {

    }

    walk() {

    }
}
```

is there a more intuitive way to do this? Of course, this is a very simplified version - but trying to go with es6 'way of doing things'.

I ended going with the following. but it still seems wrong. Your thoughts?

```
XYZ.SHOES =  new Set();
```

I believe I also tried the following and not working:

```
class XYZ {
   constructor() {
     static SHOES =  new Set(); // <-- didn't work
     this.constructor.SHOES =  new Set(); // <-- didn't work

   }
}

XYZ.SHOES =  new Set(); // <- worked
let SHOES =  new Set(); // <-- worked
```

Of course, declaring a global in the module worked AND just assigning to the class worked, but these seem dirty. Any thoughts on a more succinct approach?

Comment: So you want a *static* member of the class?

Comment: I tried, but it isn't really working.

Comment: What did you try and what was the problem?

Comment: I updated the original question with what i've tried. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I've tried adding static variable, but that isn't working with non-primitives.*"?

Comment: "*I want to add a shoe if it hasn't already been added by any other instance*" sounds like a really bad idea. That's a global variable with all its disadvantages. Better make an explicit `ShoeStore` class and pass an instance of it around to your XYZ instances.

Comment: @Bergi or he could just use a Set....

Comment: I updated. I initially thought it was a primitive issue, it wasn't. I corrected.

Comment: @bergi , so basically extend my XYZ class with this baseClass and update the parent class value, as needed?

Comment: @jamesemanon where did you get "parent class" from? If you mean my `ShoeStore` (or `Set`) class, that should be separate and each of your `XYZ` instances should have its own reference to a store instance.

Comment: Yeah, I was meaning I'd extend like so: XYZ extends ShoeStore {}, and was referring to ShoeStore as the "parent class". But, like you mentioned, I can just create one instance, and use that for the updater to the "SHOES" variable.

Comment: I ended creating a baseShoe class, instantiate that.. ala.. const newShoe = new BaseShoe();, THEN in my XYZ class I just reference my needed values like so.. newShoe.SHOES, etc.. is that what you meant @Bergi

Comment: No, I meant `const store = new Set(); var x = new XYZ(…, store)` and put the store on `this.shoeStore` inside `XYZ`

Comment: interesting. I initially had a const store = new Set(), outside and just used that. I felt there could be a more succinct way. Let me try your way. Thanks!